# Reducing the spin bordism group to its Pontryagin dual of the torsion subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, research, cobordism, surgery-theory

The spin bordism group for the classifying space $BG$ of group $G$ is denoted as $\Omega^{Spin}_d(BG)$. $\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$ are computed by [Anderson-Brown-Peterson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970690?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (D. W. Anderson, E. H. Brown, Jr. and F. P. Peterson, The structure of the Spin cobordism ring, Ann. of Math. 86, 271-298 (1967).).

> Would you be able to illuminate the following statement, in the similar context: **If a bordism group contains a free part, its Pontryagin dual has a U(1) factor. If we can ignore such continuous parameters, this is equivalent to only
>   considering the torsion subgroup of $\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$. They are the elements of the Pontryagin dual of the torsion subgroup of $\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$.**

Can one work on these statements explicitly to see what has been gone through and what has been thrown away, by reducing "$\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$" to "**the Pontryagin dual of the torsion subgroup of $\Omega^{Spin}_d(pt)$**"?